# How can WTForms RadioField generate html without <ul> and <li> tag?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms

Are there any way to replace html tag on WTForms?

Form code:

```
class BasicForm(Form):
    some_select = RadioField("something", choices=[('first', 'first_choice'), ('second', 'second_choice')])
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this at the end? If yes, I would be very happy to see some actual code if you answer your own question :)

Answer (score 1):

Your field accepts a `widget` argument you can pass to override default widget(that renders your field).

Docs:

http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field